# django lookups into a nav table in M2M relationship

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, lookup

I'm trying to write a function that would store a concatenated sting of several fields, including some stored in a relationship table of a M2M relationship.
Here is the code:

```
class substance(models.Model):
  name = models.Charfield()
  ...


class rel_med_subs(models.Model):
  id_med = models.ForeignKey(medication, related_name='relation_med')
  id_subs = models.ForeignKey(substance, related_name='relation_subs')
  order = models.IntegerField()
  strength = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
  strength_unit = models.ForeignKey(units)


class medication(models.Model):
  name = models.Charfield()
  substance = models.ManyToManyField(substance, through='rel_med_subs')
  autogenerated = models.CharField(blank=False, default='')
  ...

  def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    self.autogenerated = u'%s' % (' '.join[(u'%s %s'(s.name, s.strength) for s in self.rel_med_subs.order_by('order')])
    self(medication,self).save(force_insert,force_update
```

When I only ask for the name, the function works fine, but if I try to bring attributes from the relationship table, django complains that strength is not part of the substance model.

How can I get attributes from the relationship into my autogenerated field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `name` and `strength` attributes belong to *different* objects (`strength` belongs to `rel_med_subs`, `name` to `substance`)! You can't refer to both of them through the `(s.name, s.strength) for s in self.rel_med_subs.order_by('order')` comprehension - the `s` can only have `name` or `strength`.

It seems that the rel_med_subs attribute is a relation manager for objects of type `substance` and not of type `rel_med_subs`. Check the attributes of `medication` using `dir` to see which is the name of the manager for `rel_med_subs` (probably something like `rel_med_subs_set` -- I really can't remember it and always check it with `dir`. However be assured that `medication` will have *two* reverse relation attributes: One for the Many 2 Many relation with `substance` and one with the One 2 Many with `rel_med_subs`. After you find the correct reverse manager then you can use `s.id_subs.name` and `s.strength`.

**Also please capitalize your class names and use corrent naming** (rel_med_subs should be named MedicineSubstanceRelation) !